# fstream get method not behaving consistently

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm trying to read a file one character at a time, but for some reason the get pointers' position isn't being reported correctly:

```
std::wifstream stream(L"tokenizer.txt");

int pos = static_cast<int> (stream.tellg());

stream.get();
stream.get();

pos = static_cast<int> (stream.tellg());

stream.close();
```

The value of pos before the two calls to stream.get is 0, as it should be, but only 1 after them. The strange thing is that any calls to get after the first all affect the result of stream.tellg. In other words, the first call to get will not cause a change in result from tellg.

If I call unget after the first call to get, it still reports the position as being 0, but it treats it as being at position 1, as the next 2 characters are '/' and 'c', while they should be '/' '/'.

The contents of the file are as follows:

```
//comment
123.45 100 "delimited string" str ing
```

(The space between `str` and `ing` is intentional.)

The file itself is saved in ANSI using Notepad++.
I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiled with G++ 4.7.0 on Mac OS X 10.7.3 (that's a 'home built' compiler), then the following code, closely derived from your outline, produces the output:

```
pos = 0
c = 47
c = 47
pos = 2
```

which is what you'd expect.

Compilation command line:

```
g++ -O3 -g   -Wall -Wextra  xx.cpp -o xx
```

Actual code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(void)
{
    std::wifstream stream("tokenizer.txt");

    int pos = static_cast<int> (stream.tellg());
    std::cout << "pos = " << pos << std::endl;

    int c = stream.get();
    std::cout << "c = " << c << std::endl;

    c = stream.get();
    std::cout << "c = " << c << std::endl;

    pos = static_cast<int> (stream.tellg());
    std::cout << "pos = " << pos << std::endl;

    stream.close();
}
```

Apart from adding diagnostic printing, headers and the `main()` function, the only significant difference is that there was no constructor for `std::wifstream` that accepts an array of `wchar_t`, so I dropped the `L`.

This suggests that there is something odd about either the library you're linking with or the compiler you're using.  Could it be optimizing out one of the two calls to `get()`?  Are you sure there isn't a `//...comment ending in backslash\` on the line before one of the two calls to `get()`?

Comment: There's definitely no comments anywhere near the code, since the characters it returns show that it is incrementing the get pointer, it means that the value that tellg is returning isn't being handled correctly. I'll try to run this code in a separate project to see if it still happens.

Comment: It happens even in a separate project. I checked the assembly listing, it shows that it still calls the get method, so i don't think it's optimizing it out. I put this code in a loop and output the position and character, it says that the first 2 characters both have the 0th position. I'll try reinstalling the library, if that doesn't work i don't know what else to try.

Comment: It is beginning to sound like a bug, and more probably in the library than the compiler.  What happens if you use an `ifstream` instead of a `wifstream`?

Comment: I tried ifstream and fstream, they both have the same issue. I'm reinstalling VS2010, once it's finished i'll try again.

Comment: Have you run the test program I gave, give or take the `L` qualifier on the file name string?  If that doesn't produce `pos = 2` for the second line of output, I'm really not sure how it can be other than a bug in the system.

Comment: I used your example, adding only std::cin.get() to keep the console visible, and it gave 1 for the second position.

Comment: It doesn't often happen that such a simple program shows a bug, but it looks like it might just be the case this time.  I'm still cautious about asserting 'Bug!', but the evidence seems to be accumulating that it is.  Since it is (probably) a bug in the compiler/library combo, you are stuck with working around it, using a different technique to achieve the same effect.  If this is an exercise for university or school, take the test case to your instructor and ask for advice.  However, in the short term, it looks like you'll have to find another way to write your code to avoid problems.

Comment: This is just for a personal project, so there's no rush. If reinstalling VS doesn't fix it i'll try to download the library separately, if that won't fix it i can always try using VS 11.

Comment: I figured out why it was happening: Notepad++ saved the file incorrectly: the file has 47 characters in it, counting the newline. Notepad++ saved it as exactly 47 bytes, but Wordpad saves it as 48 bytes. Once saved by Wordpad Notepad++ will also keep it correct.

Comment: Interesting - and not obvious.  What was the difference between the 'OK' and 'not OK' files exactly?  Just one extra byte, or more differences than that?

Comment: The bad file only had 0A at the end of a line, the correct one also has 0D. This wouldn't have been a problem if Windows had been using just newlines. It's weird that not having a carriage return on position 10 affects how the character at position 0 is read.